# Git Flow Error While Cloning Repository in Visual Studios

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-flow

I am trying to clone repository in visual studios. it give me following error.

> Failed to clone the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

and when i see my output window

> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Failed to stat file 'C:/Users/../Source/Repos/......': The data area passed to a system call is too small.

but if I change my location to D:/Repositories/Abc it copies successfully.
why is this problem occuring? and one more thing it only occurs with one repository

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using visual studios 2015

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is because there is a file with a long path in the repository. When you clone it to a folder with a shorter path, it succeeds because the total number of characters in the path is below the 260 character limit. Can you check if there are files in the repository that would exceed this limit if you cloned to the deeper directory?